# Core Data: Concurrency & Serial Queues

Tags: multithreading, core-data, queue

I have been working with Core Data for some time, always learning new things about multithreading specifically. I'm currently rewriting the data model of one of my apps and have a few questions.

The Core Data model uses entities which have a constraint set (usually on the field id).
The main and background contexts use NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy, so there are no merge conflicts.

There are multiple ways for data to be added to the container.

Users can add data manually. Data can be added by fetching it from CloudKit. Data can be added by different helper classes which run on app launch (importing new data from JSON, updating existing from JSON, etc). So, potentially there can be read & write access to the persistent container from multiple threads.

Previously I have used operation queues to make access serial.

My question is: Is it enough to wrap all calls into `context.perform { }`?
Does Core Data run these serially? What happens if I use three `context.perform` calls from different classes and threads (some on the main context, some on background contexts) in parallel? Do I still need to run these on an operation queue myself to make sure they run one after another? I want to make sure that there are no concurrency crashes with Core Data and also make sure to keep the data intact at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Calls to `context.perform { }` are serial *for that context only*. You can call it as many times as you want on a context, and the calls will run in order. If you use more than one context, there's no guarantee about how one context's code will run compared to others. Since managed object contexts aren't thread safe, that *should not be a problem*, and if it is then you have other problems lurking that you would need to fix.

If for some reason you need to serialize calls that use multiple contexts, and you find that merge policies aren't enough to resolve differences, it's up to you to work out how to keep them in order.